# Do all mining pools compete to unlock same block?

Tags: mining-pools

Are all the mining pools competing to unlock each new block, or is each pool assigned an individual block to unlock?

Comment: It is the former.

Comment: Considering that there is no central authority to "assign" blocks to anybody, you should be able to work out the answer.